# Why I can't scrape success in requests but it success opened in browser

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I use the code below to **scrape** `https://mobile.lowvig.ag/sports` but it failed with 403 status code even I add headers same as browser it failed too.

```
import requests as rqs
status = rqs.get('https://mobile.lowvig.ag/sports')
print(status)
```

does someone know how to **scrape** this with requests package in python?

Comment: The link provided show an internal error ! with this message : "This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks".

Comment: Have you checked the request body? Sometimes request data is sent through the body even for GET requests.

Comment: @Fontanka16 yes I've checked the requests body the browser sends nothing just a simple GET requests same as my requests in python

Comment: If you open the link in Postman, you will see that the first request is successful, but that you then get blocked and only 403s are returned. I tried to clear out cookies, and temper with user-agents, but it seemes like something else is going on.